# how come i can echo my own php in the same page but can on another?

Tags: php, html

I made a form on echoing a user input, and it works perfect when I go lets say from index.php to second.php

but when I try to echo my post in the same index.php it gives me an error? I am confused on why. the syntax is 100% correct other wise it wont work in the 2nd page and i also looked in w3schools

sorry i tried YouTubing, and Googling, but every information transfers to the second page

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
        <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not checking for `isset` nor are you making any variables assignment. You should also name your submit button, then wrap that in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the information in the variables is ONLY available after you post (submit the form) so before you post, the $_POST array is empty.  You can do this to check for either possibility:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    $name = '';
};

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    $email = '';
};
?>
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php echo $name; ?>
        <?php echo $email; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This by the way, will cause a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- right you are; fixed

Comment: Good stuff, works beautifully. `+1`

Comment: I don't think you need to set the variables to nothing if the $_POST variable is not set.

Comment: @user2251229 you don't have to, but it's a good practice because for example I could put `value = "$name"` in the form input and it would work either way. PHP will allow you to use an uninitialized var, but it's not a good coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

You must bind your page to itself and when you click submit button it will resend the file to the browser with the code: `action=""` So that you can echo out the variables as you wish.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
        $name = '';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
        $email = '';
    }
    ?>


    <html>
        <body>

            <form action="" method="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                <input type="submit">
            </form>

            <?php echo $name; ?>
            <?php echo $email; ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**N.B.:** You can set the form's action to `action="nameofthefile.php"` if you plan on using the entire code in this answer inside two seperate pages, using the PHP and naming that file to `nameofthefile.php`

Comment: Explanation perhaps? This doesn't help the OP in no way. And the way you have it laid out now, will cause certain confusion.

Comment: Plus being copied from `Digital Chris's` answer.

Comment: It's the way I write my code. This can also be the same if its right.

Comment: Yes, but 20 minutes after I've answered it? Just upvote rather than redoing it... also the blurb at the top is wrong. If you don't supply an `action` parameter, the form will default to submitting to itself which is the behaviour we want.

Comment: Thats not the thing i'he ment. Why are you that offensive. I am tring to explain him how action="file.php" code works, I dont need to steal your answer.

Comment: Then you should split your answer into two seperate parts, if what you've shown the OP to use, the OP may very well put all that into a single file and will come back saying "It doesn't work". @OzanKurt --- This, taken from experience ;-)

Comment: Thank you for advice, ill do so next time. Thats just nonsense if i send the same, im also tring to learn here.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited your answer to better reflect the method on using your code. @OzanKurt --- It just helps to make things a bit clearer for the OP.

Comment: Cool but he wants tho see the form too... So we need to put the both in the same php file.

Comment: I re-edited it, please reload it. @OzanKurt --- I had made a slight mistake. Having it in there all in one code would not have worked. Using `action="nameofthefile.php"` as per your instructions (bind your page to itself) would have thrown an error.

Comment: Ok so how come I can just use <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> and it will echo to the other page?

Comment: You must link the first file with 'action="secondfile.php"' and then use the code '<?php $name = $_POST['name']; echo $name; ?>'

Answer (score 0):

When you load your index.php file, the server reads the PHP that exists in the file, how you don't check if the `$_POST` has values then tries to echo the values.